# CubeTextureLoader in ThreeJs not loading the background

Tags: three.js

```
//textures
let loader=new THREE.TextureLoader()
let stars = loader.load("./../static/textures/stars3.jpg");



//BACKGROUND
scene.background = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
  .load([
    "./../static/textures/stars2.jpg",
    "./../static/textures/stars3.jpg",
    "./../static/textures/stars2.jpg",
    "./../static/textures/stars3.jpg",
    "./../static/textures/stars2.jpg",
    "./../static/textures/stars3.jpg",
    
  ]);

// scene.background = loader.load(
//   "./../static/textures/stars3.jpg"
// );
```

the stars image are not showing as 3d background. When I use simple textureloader to load just one static image it works as the background but not cubetextureloader.
I don't get any errors just 3 warnings

"GL_INVALID_VALUE: Each cubemap face must have equal width and height.",

"GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Level of detail outside of range.", * 6

"GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Texture format does not support mipmap generation."

All I get is a black background.

Comment: nevermind, figured it out. The images should be square.